# XSS Attribute Protection with Symfony2/Twig

Tags: php, symfony, xss

I'm using twig to display a link which was user-provided, ie:

```
<a href="{{ project.link }}">...</a>
```

And trying to make sure its safe against XSS. I assumed Twigs built in filters would solve for this but they don't seem to. For example, if the data source is:

```
`javascript:alert("hello")`
```

The following filters fail:

```
<a href="{{ project.link|escape('html_attr') }}">...</a>   
<a href="{{ project.link|escape('url') }}">...</a>
```

The first still allows the javascript to fire, the second, if passed a full URL makes it an invalid link (ie. http://www.google.com).

Is there a twig build-in method to properly sanitize data meant for a href attribute?

Comment: Twig automatically escapes all inputs. But just to be sure, make a test, and inject some js into a input text field, and then print it out to see the result.

Comment: @DanCostinel Twig fails to escape the above data on its own, or when manually calling escape in such a way that allows real URLs to survive

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twig 3.x, you can use `escape('html')`, `escape('url')` or `escape('js')` depending on the situation.

```
<p>{{ text|escape('html')}}</p>
<a href="{{ link|escape('url') }}" onclick="console.log('{{ jsCode|escape('js') }}');">a link</a>
<script>
console.log('{{ jsCode|escape('js') }}');
</script>
```

Note that you can use the shorter syntax `e('html')`, `e('url')` or `e('js')`.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same solution and was unable to find one. Twig is wonderful at preventing specific HTML tags such as the object tag, so I compiled a list of potential javascript events that could be misused by users if they injected it into a paragraph tag or a link tag.

Using a class (or a function!) you can loop through your user submitted content and remove it. This is not an exhaustive list, I'm sure there are other avenues of attack here but this should be a starting point.

```
$badJSArray = [
    "javascript:", "content:url", "data:text", "-o-link:", "xmlns:xlink", "xlink:href", "data:image", "formaction", "onfocus", "autofocus", "onblur", "onscroll", "onforminput", "onformchange", "onerror", "oninput", "onload", "onclick", "onchange", "onmouseover", "onmouseout", "onmousedown", "onmouseup", "onbeforescriptexecute", "onresize", "onactivate", "animationstart", "animationiteration", "animationend", "transitionstart", "transitionend", "ontoggle", "onratechange", "onreadystatechange", "onfilterchange", "allowscriptaccess", "onpropertychange", "onpageshow", "onunload", "ondragstart", "ondragend", "ondrag", "ondragenter", "ondragover", "ondragleave", "ondrop", "onabort", "onemptied", "onstalled", "onsuspend", "onafterprint", "onbeforeprint", "onbeforeunload", "oncanplay", "onloadstart", "ondurationchange", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadeddata", "onprogress", "oncanplaythrough", "oncontextmenu", "oncopy", "oncut", "ondblclick", "onended", "onfocusin", "onfocusout", "fullscreenchange", "fullscreenerror", "onhashchange", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onmessage", "onopen", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmousemove", "onoffline", "ononline", "onpagehide", "onpaste", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onreset", "onsearch", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onshow", "onsubmit", "ontimeupdate", "ontouchcancel", "ontouchend", "ontouchmove", "touchcancel", "ontouchstart", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onwheel"
];


class CleanXSS {
    function js($value) {
        global $badJSArray;
        return str_ireplace($badJSArray, "data-inert", $value);
    }
}

$CleanXSS = new CleanXSS();

echo $CleanXSS->js("<p onclick='alert(1)'>Hello World!</p>");





// Or create a simple function
function CleanXSS($value) {
    global $badJSArray;
    return str_ireplace($badJSArray, "data-inert", $value);
}

echo CleanXSS("<p onclick='alert(1)'>Hello World!</p>");





// Create a Twig filter to use in the templates
$CleanXSSFilter = new \Twig\TwigFilter('CleanXSS', function ($value) {
    global $badJSArray;
    return str_ireplace($badJSArray, "data-inert", $value);
});


// Add filter to the global twig variable list
$twig->addFilter($CleanXSSFilter);
```

example of using this in a twig file

```
<div class="col-lg-8 team-profiles">
{{ team.page_content|CleanXSS|striptags('<p><b><i><a>')|raw}}
</div><!-- end column -->
```

I gathered this list from these two resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

https://html5sec.org/

Hopefully this helps your project!

---

## Update!

An easy way is to set a CORS policy meta tag to prevent inline JS from firing! Easy peasy!

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [escape](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html) function.

> The escape filter can also be used in other contexts than HTML thanks
>   to an optional argument which defines the escaping strategy to use:

Example:

```
{{ 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161675/xss-attribute-protection-with-symfony2-twig<script>alert(1)</script>' | e('html') }}
```

Comment: Apologies; in the question above I incorrectly typed `encode` when I'd used `escape` -- it is in fact `escape` which fails to prevent XSS in a usable fashion. ie. `<a href='{{ 'javascript:alert("hi")' | escape('html') }}'>test</a>`

Comment: @just.another.newbie use `escape('js')` then